# If I do a sin unknowingly, is it a sin?

Tags: salat, sin

Before I reached the age of puberty, my mother said I offer Salah too fast, so when she was in the room, I used to stay in Qayam for a bit after reciting Suraahs and then go to sajidah.

Comment: Only those actions matter, for which you ntended to do. so your intentions matter. hence, the sin which you did unknowingly, wont be counted

Comment: just add one more thing, what is sin and what is not you need to know. And for this Ilm (knowledge) is Farz (Obligatory).

Answer (score 3):

There are two groups of ignorant in Islam:

**1**.Culpable ignorant: People who have failed in fulfilling their duties due to negligence and  irresponsibility. For instance, Although they are fully aware of being obliged to a certain set of duties, they are too irresponsible to make any effort to find out about them.

**2**.Inculpable ignorant: People who have failed in their obligations in spite of the fact that they have tried their best to find out about them.

Although one of the condition without which one cannot be considered among sinners is awareness(to be fully aware that, for instance, watching porn movies is a sin), the first group will definitely be among sinners and the blame of this ignorance lies with them owing to them being negligent and irresponsible.

The second group will not receive any punishment but in certain cases they have to make up for the obligations they have failed in. For example, not offering the daily prayers in the prescribed times.

There are just a few cases in which even the first group is not obliged to compensate for anything. For instance:

> It is Wajib(obligatory) for a man to recite Surah al-Hamd and the other Surah
>   loudly, while offering Fajr, Maghrib(sunset) and Isha prayers, and it is Wajib
>   for a man and a woman to recite Surah al-Hamd and the other Surah
>   silently while offering Zuhr(noon) and Asr(afternonn) prayers. ([Source](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2221/))

However, if a person recited loudly where he should recite silently and vice versa, his prayer would be in order as long as he has not recited so intentionally. So he does not have to make up for his prayers even though he is a culpable ignorant about this rule.

And Last but not Least: one is free from any responsibilities and obligations as long as he or she has not reached puberty. However, people's right is the only exception which means that if an immature person (for example) stole something, he or she would be obliged to return it or pay a compensation for it as soon as he or she reaches puberty even though this person is not considered a sinner.

Comment: Hmm, your general criteria seems sound, but can someone really not know that watching porn for example is morally heinous? I think Divine exemption on ignorance excuse only applies to those sins who can not be identified by human God-given consciousness as such for example looking at non-hijabi woman or not paying charity for example, but crimes that are identifiable by human common sense such as murder or watching porn are not subject to the rule. That's what I think based on my knowledge of religion workings.

Comment: infatuated@ This is an answer to a question raised by a Muslim who believes in God, His rules and regulations in general and the Day of Judgement when people receive their rewards and punishments. So I don't think that the criteria you've mentioned is applicable in this case. However, it requires further discussion as to whether the sins identifiable by human common sense fall into the first category.

Answer (score 0):

No. Al-bagharah 286.
You will be asked due to your abilities.

Solution is tobah (repentance) and never do the sin again God is the greatest forgiver.

But take care after tobah if your sin damaged anybody you should take care of him/her and recover the damage. God will not ignore human rights which damaged by you in next world even after tobah. But if you stay on your tobah inshallah he will ignore his rights you broke with your sin.